# How to access localhost by IP address?

Tags: localhost, xampp

I am trying to access localhost by my IP address. My IP address is/was `217.164.79.62` (It is set to be automatically assigned so it keeps changing).

When I visit `http://localhost/`, I get the XAMPP homepage.

However, when I visit `http://217.164.79.62/`, I get the following message:

> The server 217.164.79.62:80 requires a
>   username and password.
>
> User Name:
>   Password:

How do I get the username and password?

Answer (score 16):

To access the server from itself, use `http://localhost/` or `http://127.0.0.1/`.

To access the server from a separate computer on the same network, use `http://192.168.X.X` where `X.X` is your server's local IP address. You can find the sever's local IP address (assuming it's Linux) by running `hostname -I`.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 works on this computer but it does not work on other computers. `http://217.164.79.62/` works on any computer in my network but requests username and password... ;(  Sorry for taking so long. I hadn't expected answers this quickly. :D

Comment: Problem solved. I can access the computer by using 192.168.254.4. :D Thanks for all the help! :D

Comment: @Malte Werschy: Sorry, I must have missed your reply until now. I've updated my answer with information about local IPs (`192.168.X.X`) which should hopefully allow you to bypass whatever security policy is denying you access.

Answer (score 7):

`http://localhost` is NOT the same as `http://217.164.79.62`

The `localhost` address is 99.999% of the time mapped to the IP address `127.0.0.1` and is totally inaccessible from anywhere except your local machine

What you're finding when you're entering `http://217.164.79.62` is that your modem/router device owns that IP address, so you're getting the login screen for it.

Comment: So i need the password of the modem?

Comment: @Malte - no, you clearly didn't read what I wrote. You don't want to use `217.164.79.62` - you want to use `127.0.0.1`. If you're trying to get other people to see your site (you don't mention this in your question), then this is another matter alltgoether.

Answer (score 5):

Do you have a Modem/router type device to connect to the internet? It sounds like you are connecting to the configuration interface for this.

Alternatively: On what platform do you use XAMPP? Could you post the output of ipconfig in Windows or sudo ifconfig in Linux/MacOS?

--- Edit

OK, so with the info you gave here, it is now clear what the problem is (and that this belongs on superuser.com instead of Serverfault).

When you try to connect to your public IP address, you are in fact reaching your router, not your XP box. If you really would want to connect to the XAMPP server with this public IP address, you would need to configure your router to forward port 80 to your XP machine so that it is accessible from the outside (you will find how that is done in the routers documentation). However, this is a terrible idea if you just want to test things and don't need others to access it. Instead, you would either use `127.0.0.1`, which would only work on your XP box, or `192.168.254.4`, which would be accessible from any computer in your home LAN.

Could you edit your original question and tell us why you want to use the IP address instead of `http://localhost`in the first place?

NB: The info you gave on the router/modem stated that it's firewall is deactivated. This is normally a really bad idea, I would strongly recommend turning it on. How this is done will also be explained in the documentation.

Comment: Yes I do have a modem. The ip address of the modem is 192.168.254.254. The data report of the modem is:

System Type: SpeedStream 6520 Series
DSL Connection Information: UP
Router IP Address: 192.168.254.254
WAN IP Address: 217.164.79.62
Firewall: Off
Config Part #: 003-a193-G02
Firmware Part #: 004-E752-A64
MAC Address: 00:13:A3:D0:FB:2A
Up Time: 0 days, 21 hours, 6 minutes, 36 seconds

I use xampp on windows xp. the output of ipconfig is:  

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

     Conection-specific DNS Sufix  . : domain.invalid

Continued in next post.

Comment: What is it with this formatting? Am I doing something wrong? How do I get {enter_key}? Anyway continued report is: IP Address: 192.168.254.4  Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0                                             IP Address: fe80::203:dff:fe44:41df%4                                  Default Gateway: 192.168.254.254                                    Ethernet adapter Wireless Network Connection:                       Media State: Media disconnected                                     Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:                   Connection-specific DNS Sufix: {Continued}

Comment: IP Address: fe80::ffff:ffff:fffd%6  Default Gateway:  Tunnel adapter Automatic Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:  Connection-specific DNS Suffix:  IP Address: fe80:ffff:ffff:fffd%6  Default Gateway:  Tunnel adapter Automatic Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:  Connection-specific DNS Suffix: domain.invalid  IP Address: fe80::5efe:192.168.254.4%2  Default Gateway: I am really sorry for this formatting. ;( I just don't know how to do it better... ;(

Comment: Malte, I edited my answer with some more infos. Also, it should be possible for you to edit your question to append infos like the above. Doing this in the question instead of a comment makes it easier to format and easier to find.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to connect to your modem. That means you haven't configured in your modem for your static IP...if you don't have a static IP, you can't route to port 80 with this IP address...and this shows, you can't log in to localhost with this ip...use 127.0.0.1 to connect localhost instead of this, if you don't have a static IP and if you haven't configured your router...

Comment: Please, I'm new to this. I don't really understand what you mean. ;) Can you explain please? thanks.